# Would the existence of planets (rocks) be still possible if gravity was the only force?

Tags: forces

Our atoms are hold together by EM-force and a lot of particles itself are often hold together by the strong force. But imagine that only gravity would exist under what conditions would it be possible to still get some big rocks or even planets?

Would the minimum or maximum size of planets be different?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Some general remarks:

- This universe would be different enough from ours that there is no way to relate its time/distance scale to ours. E.g., we can't refer to "1 second" in that universe. Therefore we can't talk about that universe "at the same stage in its evolution" as ours, and we can't necessarily depend on our intuition about how long it takes for various processes to happen.
- To make a real answer possible, we would need to redefine the whole standard model. E.g., do the photon, gluon, W, and Z still exist, but with zero coupling to fermions, or do they not exist at all?

Rocks won't exist, since the stability of bulk matter depends on both the Pauli exclusion principle [and the properties of electromagnetic interactions](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119495/mathematical-proof-of-the-stability-of-atoms/119528).

If we have massive fermions, then they will form objects analogous to neutron stars.

The cosmological constant will presumably be nonzero in this universe, although we can't compare its strength to the strength it has in our universe, since we don't have a common system of units. If it's large enough, it could prevent the formation of structure.

Our universe had a low-entropy big bang, with the gravitational degrees of freedom (such as gravitational waves) excited to a much lower degree than would be the case in the most probable (maximum entropy) big bang. It's hard to know how to compare this to your universe, in which gravitational degrees of freedom are sort of the only degrees of freedom.

Black holes (or gravitational collapse resulting in other types of singularities) are a generic feature of GR, as shown by the Penrose singularity theorem. Black holes can form from colliding gravitational waves, and this process increases entropy. Therefore collapse to black holes is possible in your universe.

Answer (score 0):

No other forces means no interactions other than gravitational interactions. Means all matter would be dark matter. No rocks, but there would be halos hovering together under influence of gravity.

No other repulsions/attractions means no charges, things do not get deflected/reflected, they can pass through one another.

It would also mean no electromagnetic waves, so no light, it would be a totally dark universe.

Just at the time of big bang, there could have been a tiny moment when there was only gravity, and no other forces.

Comment: That last phrase of yours: we don't know that, do we?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis: There was only one unified property (force) in beginning and gravity was first to born from it. Other forces separated (came into being) later. http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_bigbang_timeline.html. Although other forces can be considered present alongside gravity in unified form. But we can not call that a force, because we do not know anything about its behavior.

Comment: Sorry but we have no theory unifying gravity with the Standard Model. We have hypotheses, hopes, speculations, but no theory, and that web site you quoted honestly states it (emphasis mine): « it is *hypothesized* that the four fundamental forces (electromagnetism, weak nuclear force, strong nuclear force and gravity) all have the same strength, and are *possibly even* unified into one fundamental force»